# What does it mean to "retire a risk"?

Tags: phrases

Today I used the phrase "retire that risk" and realized I didn't know what it meant. I've heard the phrase used by NASA, [for example here](https://www.nasa.gov/seh/6-4-technical-risk-management):

> Systems engineers are involved in this process to help...determine if new risks arise or old risks can be retired...

The usage sounds similar to "retire a debt", which I find to be another puzzling construction.

- Does "retiring a risk" simply mean eliminating it? Or does it require elimination by virtue of passage if time?
- What's the origin of this phrasing and is there an intuitive meaning behind it?

Comment: This isn't a common usage. I wonder whether the real key is a non-standard meaning for "risk," perhaps one that means "an entry tracking a risk in some kind of organizational system"

Comment: @AndyBonner the expression would be readily understandable by anyone who uses a risk management framework. If a particular risk in the organisation's Risk Register is no longer applicable (e.g. a risk related to sales of BitBots, except that division was sold to another company and the risk no longer exists), you would *retire it* from the register. Perhaps not very common, but it's perfectly standard: see [MW's usage 1 for the transitive verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retire). The question lacks research.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica I'm new to this stack exchange. How should I have researched better before asking the question? Thanks.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica, as you are familiar with the actual use of the term, it seems that your answer would be a helpful addition to the ones already posted. Could you be persuaded to post it? Your comment hints that *retire the risk* (in the relevant jargon) is a broader concept than *eliminate the risk* (in everyday English), and it would be helpful to future visitors to this page to have that articulated in an answer (more helpful than closing the question).

Comment: retire a risk = recognize something is no longer a risk.

Comment: @Doug Re research: for meaning or usage, I look the word up in an online lexicon (try [Onelook](https://www.onelook.com/) for options). For synonyms, a thesaurus. Or [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/) [which says *retire* "meaning 'to remove from active service' is from 1680s"]. For grammar, I search EL&U first, then go to Wikipedia. Lastly, I search the expression using a search engine. If your research doesn't resolve the issue, by all means ask a question here *including the research you've done*. We really welcome good questions: see [ask] for further tips, and *take our [Tour]!* :-)

Comment: @jsw29 As the usage is perfectly standard, and consistent with the dictionary meaning, I voted to close the question as lacking in research. It would be rank hypocrisy to then post an answer to a question I believe is off-topic.

Comment: @Doug A "lacking in research" question can become useful if you focus on a specific aspect of meaning or usage. For example, you might ask whether "retire risk" is just a US usage? [This n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=retire_INF+risk%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t3%3B%2Cretire_INF%20risk%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bretire%20risk%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bretired%20risk%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bretiring%20risk%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0) shows US usage taking off in the 1990s, but substitute GB for US & you get zero!

Comment: In sales it is very common to speak of “retiring quota”, ie making sales and generating revenue, moving your closer to satisfying your quota and earning maximum commissions.

Answer (score 4):

The earliest examples I have found so far are:

> Mr. GOLDIN [NASA Administrator] ... I want to solve this specific
> problem. I want to make a casting with small grain size and high
> strength. I want to understand the mechanical characteristics of the
> ball bearings. I want to take the vibrational problems out of the
> system. You could do that. You could **retire the risk**, if you
> will, and then proceed on with the program and not have the type of
> problems that we have had. [*US Congress Hearing, NASA Fiscal Year 1993 Oversight*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Departments_of_Veterans_Affairs_and_Hous/IgJ0QXY-a_YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22retire%20the%20risk%22&pg=PA47&printsec=frontcover)

(Note the *if you will* in the above, perhaps suggesting the speaker thinks the expression may be unfamiliar to the audience.)

> ... get the money to build a follow-on to the Shuttle. We can make it possible for the industry to do that. We are trying to do that in two ways. The first is to reduce the technical risk with technology programs
> that will allow industry to conclude with a high degree of certainty
> that the **risk has been retired**. [*Aerospace America*, vol. 33,
> p.12](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Aerospace_America/67-wAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22risk%20has%20been%20retired%22&dq=%22risk%20has%20been%20retired%22&printsec=frontcover) (1995, Google Books snippet)

This terminology in Risk Management, which appears to have begun in the aerospace industry, is used by the US Department of Defense:

> Communicating and Feedback Process – Process for communicating the
> status of potential, current, and **retired risks** as well as
> opportunities that may exist to all personnel involved in risk
> management  (p.9)
> ...
> Once a program team has determined that the mitigation strategy for a
> risk is to control it, part of the control plan may include a risk
> burn-down plan for high risks. For most risks the burn-down plan
> consists of steps, tied to the project schedule, that allow the
> program to control the risk and **retire risks**. (p.36)
> [DOD Risk Management Guide for Defense Acquisition Programs](https://acqnotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/DoD-Risk-Mgt-Guide-v7-interim-Dec2014.pdf) (2014)

I was led to the DOD Guide from this webpage:

> Question
>
> Is there any template of questions or criteria that could be
> used for a risk to meet in order to be **realized, retired, or
> identified?**
>
> Answer
>
> This is an excellent question because it gets at the heart of good
> risk management.  In order to answer it, we should first discuss the
> Program Risk Process (PRP) in general.
> ...
>
> **Risk Identification**.  Per the DoD Risk, Issue, and Opportunity
> Management Guide (RIO Guide), Jan 2017, risk identification occurs
> after the process planning step.
>
> **Risk Realization**. Risk realization means the risk is no longer a risk
> (something that may occur in the future) since it has come to
> fruition.  Just ask, did this risk actually occur?  If so, it is an
> issue (assuming it is problematic).  ...
>
> **Risk Retirement**. There are multiple ways to **retire a risk or an issue**.  It becomes
> a judgment call as to the appropriate time to take it off your RIO
> rhythm.  You could consider questions like:  Does this risk warrant
> any more tracking or mitigation actions?   **Has this risk come to
> fruition and is no longer an issue?**  [DAU company webpage](https://www.dau.edu/aap/pages/ArticleContent.aspx?itemid=19378)

Comment: Nice answer, @DjinTonic. I am wondering if the risk of the O rings on the Challenger failing can be retired after the Challenger blows up?

Comment: @Xanne Thank you.  I thought about adding that speculation and even looked it up. It happened  nine years earlier.

Comment: @Xanne Thank you. Yes, quite possibly. I thought of adding that speculation and even looked it up. The Challenger disaster was in 1986. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to move the snippet any higher.

Comment: It might be helpful if it could be made explicit exactly how *retire the risk* differs from *eliminate the risk* (apart from the former belonging to a jargon and the latter to everyday English).

Comment: @jsw29 I agree, but I can't distinguish the nuances from just these examples. It appears this is part of a formal process in risk management. It might be that *retire* means it's been judged that the risk is not current *and* is highly unlikely to occur in the future, as the last paragraph in the examples suggests. I certainly wouldn't use or expect to hear this expression in everyday English. I peeked at some books on risk management in Google Books, but they were not searchable.

Comment: The last two paragraphs of the last quotation seem to be at odds with each other. The first of the two says that a risk's coming to 'fruition' is an issue, while the second implies that a risk's coming to 'fruition' makes it no longer an issue.

Comment: @jsw29 I can only speculate: perhaps the *and* in the last paragraph means the risk became a reality *and/but* has passed/ended. Perhaps there are some risks that can happen only once, so once they occur, you can take them off your list (?) The webpage says "DAU offers a Risk Management Workshop." -- I might need one to decipher the jargon.

Comment: The DOD Guide has this on p.39: "Document risks that can be retired as well as risks that are still being managed to avoid
unnoticed relapse of the retired risk" It beats me how a "retired risk" can relapse. Does it come out of retirement?

Answer (score 1):

The use of the term *risk* by NASA is specific and may be peculiar to NASA.

See https://www.nasa.gov/seh/6-4-technical-risk-management.

Because NASA’s own documents define their use of the term, their own definition of risks (and the retirement thereof) is paramount in any use of the term by them.